# Will DCUO trophies pop as soon as I get Legendary?

Tags: ps3, dc-universe-online

If I complete feats required for trophies, (e.g. get a platinum in a race, or reach level 10 with a tank) and then buy a legendary membership, will the trophies pop?

There are ways to cheat ps3 trophies (loading a 100% saved file) and once the game sees the full save file the trophies pop. Now it depends on how DCUO does the check for trophies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All trophies are retroactive. Once you go Legendary, any feats you earned that are also trophies will immediately unlock

and yes i am sure

Comment: Is this true? Are you certain?

Comment: I am sure that this will work

Comment: Upvoted and accepted, don't know downvoted